# What is the precise definition of connect semisimple Lie groups "without compact factors" in the literature?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

I frequently see in the literature (of homogeneous dynamics, in particular) of the notion "semisimple Lie groups without compact factors" without seeing its precise definition.

I have three (or rather, four) interpretations:

---

(1) A semisimple Lie group $G$ is "without compact factors" iff it cannot be decomposed nontrivially as $G=G_1 \cdots G_n$ such that one of $G_i$ is a connected, compact, normal Lie group.

(2) By the definition at the bottom of [this notes by Yves Benoist](https://bremy.perso.math.cnrs.fr/smf_sec_18_04.pdf#page=23#), a factor of $G'$ a Lie group $G$ is a quotient of $G$. So "without compact factors" means "no nontrivial compact quotients"

(3) A semisimple Lie group $G$ is "without compact factors" iff its Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ has a root space decomposition

$$\frak{g}=\frak{h}\oplus_{\alpha \in \Phi} \frak{g}_\alpha,$$

and none of these factors is a compact Lie algebra.

However, compact Lie algebras have [two in-general-nonequivalent definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Lie_algebra):

(3.1) A compact Lie algebra is the Lie algebra of a compact Lie group.

(3.2) A compact Lie algebra is a real Lie algebra whose Killing form is negative definite.

(4)  (Heard from a talk, not very sure) A connected semisimple Lie group without compact factors is a connected semisimple Lie group all of whose connected, normal, compact subgroups are trivial.

---

Which of (1),(2.1),(2.2),(3) are equivalent for a connected semisimple Lie group $G$?

So which definition is the "canonical" definition of "connected semisimple Lie group without compact factors". I personally care more about homogeneous dynamics. Examples of literature containing semisimple Lie groups without compact factor:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506531.pdf
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.05256.pdf

Comment: For $G$ a connected semisimple Lie group, all the following equivalent conditions mean the same as "is without noncompact factor": (i) every compact normal subgroup of $G$ is finite (i) every nontrivial connected closed normal subgroup is non-compact (iii) every simple quotient is non-compact (iv) every simple quotient with trivial center is non-compact (v) every compact quotient is trivial (vi) no nontrivial direct factor of its Lie algebra has a negative-definite Killing form

Comment: (1) is too vague (you don't say what "nontrivially" means. (3) is vague and sounds very strange (since in a root grading, the homogeneous components are not "factors"). Root space decomposition is quite more elaborate and the first thing you consider for a semisimple Lie algebra is its decomposition as direct product of simple Lie algebras. And anyway for a semisimple Lie algebra, compact means indifferently "is the Lie algebra of some compact Lie group" and "every connected Lie group with this as Lie algebra, is compact".

Comment: Anyway in terms of grading, one still has: a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is compact iff every torsion-free abelian group $A$ (or just for $A=\mathbf{Z}$) every grading $\mathfrak{g}=\bigoplus_{a\in A}\mathfrak{g}_a$ is trivial (i.e. $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_0$). To characterize no compact factor, one has anyway: $\mathfrak{g}$ has no compact factor iff it admits a grading in some torsion-free abelian group (one can choose $\mathbf{Z}$) such that $\mathfrak{g}_0$ contains no nonzero ideal.